# Passing coordinates of selected Annotation to new View Controller Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, mapkit, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, mapkitannotation

I am trying to pass the coordinates, title, and subtitle of a selected MKAnnotation from ViewController1 (VC1) to ViewController2 (VC2) when the DetailDisclosure button of rightCalloutAccessoryView is tapped. I have a segue from VC1 to VC2 with the identifier viaSegue. I have a label with identifier viaSegueLabel in VC2 where I want to display the coordinates as a String.

The function that customizes the MKAnnotation's call out so that it displays a DetailDisclosure button in the rightCalloutAccessoryView looks like:

```
// Customize Annotation Callout
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        // 1
        let identifier = "Capital"

        // 2
        if annotation.isKindOfClass(Capital.self) {
            // 3
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

            if annotationView == nil {
                //4
                annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:identifier)
                annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

                // 5
                let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
                annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            } else {
                // 6
                annotationView!.annotation = annotation
            }

            return annotationView
        }

        // 7
        return nil
    }
```

The function that takes the user from VC1 to VC2 when the DetailDisclosure button is tapped looks like:

```
// When righCalloutAccessoryView is tapped, segue to newView
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newView", sender: view)
}
```

And the function I think I need to implement to accomplish this looks like:

```
// Pass data to newView
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "newView") {
        let destViewController:BusStopSettingsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BusStopSettingsViewController
        destViewController.viaSegue = // not sure how to reference selected Annotation here
    }
}
```

**In the last line of prepareForSegue(), I need to reference the MKAnnotation that is currently selected. Is there a method built into Swift that lets me do this, or should I make the Annotation global?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out in case anyone in the future needs to implement something similar.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newView", sender: view)
```

programmatically segues your program to the View Controller (VC) that is connected to the VC you are currently in through a segue with identifier `"newView"`. Before it completely segues, the program calls `prepareForSegue()`. This function is where you will handle sending information to the VC you are segueing to. My issue was, I didn't know exactly what I was sending (in terms of type, variable name, etc.). If you notice, `prepareForSegue()` and `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newView", sender: view)` both have a parameter **sender**. What you send using `performSegueWithIdentifier()` will be passed into `prepareForSegue()` and will be received in your `destinationViewController` by a variable with the name **viaSegue**. This isn't a standard name, it's just what I chose to name that variable and if you study the code above, you'll see where it's used and how it works.

So I wanted to send information about an MKAnnotation I had tapped. So, I needed to send an Object of type MKAnnotationView to my receiving VC "BusStopSettingsViewController" (BSSVC). In BSSVC, I needed a variable called "viaSegue" of type MKAnnotationView. To send BSSVC an object of type MKAnnotationView I needed to do

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "newView") {
        // pass data to next view
        let destViewController:BusStopSettingsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BusStopSettingsViewController
        destViewController.viaSegue = sender as! MKAnnotationView
    }
}
```

Notice how `viaSegue` is specified as the variable that'll be receiving this object.

Hope this helps!